# Get ylimits and xlimits of matplotlib subplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, subplot, axes

I'm trying to get the ylim of matplotlib subplot. I want to get the range i.e. xlim and ylim of each row.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig1, fig1_axs = plt.subplots(
            nrows=5, ncols=3,
            figsize=(18, 20),
        )
....
plt.getp(fig1_axs[1, :], 'ylim')
```

but this returns the following error

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_ylim'
```

I basically want to get the ylim of each row i.e. max value and set the ymax to all the columns in the same row.

Suggestions will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as the error is saying `fig1_axs[1, :]` is a numpy array, and numpy arrays do not have an attribute 'get_ylim', which is what `getp` tries to apply to it's first argument.

`matplotlib.pyplot.getp` works only on individual matplotlib artists, so you'll need to iterate over each axes in the row and determine the max value. Then iterate over them again to set the limits.

```
max_y = -float('inf') # Choose a big number of inf
row = fig1_axs[1, :]
for ax in row:
    y = plt.getp(ax, 'ylim')
    if y[1] > max_y: 
        max_y = y[1]
```